# Couldn't register a user on Firebase android

Tags: android

```
private void registerUser(String email, String password){
    if(validEmail && validPassword){
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(Register.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "success" + task.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, task.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

I tried this on android studio and the task.isSuccessful() is always false. Below here I attached the error code from logcat.

D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x947ea060: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0f23db0)
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x947ea060: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0f23db0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x947ea060: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0f23db0)

The return message from the else statement is com.google.android.gms.task.zzn@xxxxxxx. Can anyone tell me what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the error message use this code:

```
Exception exception = task.getException();
Toast.makeText(Register.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The method `toString()` is not implemented to show an error message.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It works and I did get the message which is com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Access Not Configured. Google Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project '' before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project='' then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

Comment: I enabled the google map api which I will be using for my app but stil getting the same error. Maybe I did not wait long enough?

Comment: Finally I figured it out. At the console.developers.google.com page, I typed in "identity toolkit" at the search bar, click on the identity toolkit and enable it. I need to dive a little bit deeper to get it